# Multiline support in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, kendo-grid, multiline

I am having a column with following definition in Kendo UI Grid

```
fields: {
        column1: {type:"string",editable: false},
}

columns: [
{field: "column1",title:"Column1",width: 600}, 
]
```

The column is having VARCHAR2(4000) as a data size in DB and can have huge data with few paragraphs. Obviously it is having more than one lines.

The column when entered is being stored in DB with carriage returns and special characters.

But when it is rendered in Kendo UI Grid all the characters appear in single line.

For editing I can apply textarea editor and multiple lines can be viewed.

```
var textEditorInitialize = function(container, options) {
        $('<textarea name="' + options.field + '" style="width: ' + container.width() + 'px;height:' + container.height() + 'px" />').appendTo(container);
    };
```

But, how to display the data in multi-lines for this column when viewed in grid?

Tried searching this on dev forums but haven't got any faithful inputs.

Do suggest any links/pointers for the same.

Comment: Do you somewhere have a public repository of this code? I am trying to do exactly what you described: make multi line edition. But I am trying to do in Angular and I dont understand where to add this, so looking at your code might help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style the cells with `white-space: pre-line`. This will collapse most whitespace, but line break at newlines (plus on `<br/>`).

Comment: Thanks Richard ! It worked:

.k-grid-content tr td {
      white-space: pre-line
  }

Comment: Thanks, I got it work by
.k-grid td { 
        white-space: pre-line !important
    }